# How can I write a file with a data stored in a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I stored the data in a dictionary something like this:

```
Data = {'Key1': np.array([0., 3., 4., ..., 0., 4., 5.]),
'Key2': np.array([2., 1., 6., ..., 2., 4., 5.]),
'Key3': np.array([0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 0.]),
'Key4': np.array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 2., 0.]),
'Key5': np.array([0., 1., 2., ..., 0., 0., 0.])}
```

Now I need to create a file and store this data in the form of columns like this:

```
Data.txt
Key1   Key2   Key3   Key4   Key5
0       2      0      0      0
3       1      0      0      1
4       6      0      0      2
...
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python read store data", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: I'll try to keep this things in mind the next time, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does a good job with this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_data).to_csv("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pandas Dataframe and write it to a file:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data)
>>> df.to_csv(r'Data.txt', index=False, header=True, sep='\t')
>>> df
Key1   Key2   Key3   Key4   Key5
0       2      0      0      0
3       1      0      0      1
4       6      0      0      2
```